Why can't I modify the 'y' aesthetic when stat_summary uses the median function?
I'm working with R and the ggplot2 package. I have the following code snippets:
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

d + stat_summary(fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 4,
                 geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(y)),
                 position = position_nudge(x = 0.25))  # This works fine.

However, when I change the geom to "point" and try to specify the y aesthetic, it throws an error:
d + stat_summary(fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 4,
                 geom = "point", aes(y = after_stat(y)),
                 position = position_nudge(x = 0.25))

The error message is:
Error in `stat_summary()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
! `stat_summary()` requires the following
  missing aesthetics: y.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `stat_summary()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
! `stat_summary()` requires the following
  missing aesthetics: y.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5.     └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
  6.       ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
  7.       │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
  8.       │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  9.       │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 10.       │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 11.       │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.       └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13.         └─l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
 14.           └─ggplot2 (local) compute_statistic(..., self = self)
 15.             └─self$stat$compute_layer(data, self$computed_stat_params, layout)
 16.               └─ggplot2 (local) compute_layer(..., self = self)

I'm not sure why I can't seem to modify the y aesthetic when using the median function with stat_summary and a geom of "point". Any insights or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here is an another example.This code works.
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, displ)) +
  geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(
      y = stage(displ, after_stat = 8),
      label = after_stat(paste(mean, "±", sd))
    ),
    geom = "text",
    fun.data = ~ round(data.frame(mean = mean(.x), sd = sd(.x)), 2)

But when I change it to this
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, displ)) +
  geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(
    aes(
      y = 8,
      label = after_stat(paste(mean, "±", sd))
    ),
    geom = "text",
    fun.data = ~ round(data.frame(mean = mean(.x), sd = sd(.x)), 2)
  )

I just get this message
Error in `stat_summary()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_text()` requires the following missing
  aesthetics: y.


Assuming the goal is to plot a point at the median, you can remove the aesthetic mapping in stat_summary. Delete aes(y = ...) and your code example will work.

Thank you for your response. Removing the aesthetic mapping indeed makes the code work. However, I am still curious as to why label = after_stat(y) is able to work while y = after_stat(y) doesn't.

In the first non-working example the error message is telling you what's the issue:

stat_summary() requires the following missing aesthetics: y.

i.e. you have to map a variable on y.
In the first working code you are mapping mpg on y which is passed on to stat_summary to compute the median of mpg for each value of cyl aka the variable mapped on x. In this case, you can e.g. use after_stat to add the computed value as a label.
However, using y = after_stat(y) will not work as you are overwriting the mapping y = mpg. Hence, you are no longer mapping a variable on y, and as stat_summary can't compute a value based on nothing, it will complain with the above error message. In some sense, you are running in circles when you do y = after_stat(y).
And for the simple example there is of course no reason to do y = after_stat(y) as stat_summary will already map the y value computed under the hood on the y aesthetic after the stat has been applied, i.e. it does what stage is doing.
Hence, if you require an after_stat computation on y aesthetic then use stage, i.e. y = stage(mpg, after_stat = y) will work:
library(ggplot2)

d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

d + stat_summary(
  fun = "median", colour = "red", size = 4,
  geom = "text",
  aes(
    y = stage(mpg, after_stat = y),
    label = after_stat(y)
  ),
  position = position_nudge(x = 0.25)
)


In your second, non-working example the issue is simply that your stats function does not contain a y column. From the docs (?stat_summary), fun.data should be :

A function that is given the complete data and should return a data frame with variables ymin, y, and ymax.

However, the function you pass to fun.data will return a data.frame with columns mean and sd only. This is no issue when you do y = stage(displ, after_stat = 8) as in this case you are adding or creating the y column using an after_stat calculation. But when you do y = 8 the data after the stat has been applied does not contain a y column and hence is missing the required information to place the label.
Of course is y = 8 completely different from y = stage(displ, after_stat = 8) (which I think is what you want) but if you really want y = 8 then you can rename the mean column, i.e. use y instead of mean in fun.data or use stage to map mean on y after the stat has been applied, i.e.  y = stage(8, after_stat = mean).
